# Does DiSEqC require a DC bias?

Tags: rf, signal, coax, coupling, satellite

The DiSEqC (Di[gital] S[attelite] Eq[uipment] C[ontrol] specification (bus_spec.pdf within https://www.eutelsat.com/files/PDF/DiSEqC-documentation.zip) describes a tone-based serial data bus that can share coax with an RF signal.

The spec mentions LNB/switch power and the legacy 13V/18V legacy signalling method, and mentions a long-term desired/recommended 12V power level.  But in my reading of the spec, despite these "recommendations", nowhere is any DC bias ***required*** (using the magic "must" and "shall" words).

Is it legal/valid to couple DiSEqC tones without a DC bias?

Answer (score 0):

It uses 22kHz burst communication in this interface rev, not DC control.

[REF](https://www.eutelsat.com/files/PDF/DiSEqC-documentation.zip) *To permit slave devices to communicate back to the master, it is necessary to make more specific recommendations for the operating impedances of the bus than is required for a simple 22 kHz continuous tone signalling. In addition, it is advantageous to be able to accept a wide range of DC operating voltages during the DiSEqC introductory phase, to permit compatible and/or hybrid operation with the present signalling methods.*

*The recommendations for operation of the DiSEqC Bus are: The long-term recommendation for the DC Supply voltage is 12 ± 1 volts, but during the introductory phase, voltages up to 20 volts should be tolerated by peripheral devices (i.e. not suffer catastrophic failures). For the short term, some manufacturers may choose to retain compatibility with 13/18 volt signalling levels, and this facility is supported in the first versions of the DiSEqC Slave integrated circuit.*

*It is recommended that Tuner-receiver/IRDs should support a DC Supply
current drain of up to 500 mA for peripheral devices powered by the Bus.   The nominal 22 kHz signalling amplitude is 650 mV (±250 mV) peak-peak.
To accommodate tolerances and voltage drop in the cable, the detector should respond to amplitudes down to approximately 300 mV (±100 mV). The maximum recommended amplitude to be applied to the bus is 1 volt peak to peak*

Comment: Yes, I read that in the spec as well.  But nowhere does it state that 0V (the absence of an explicit voltage) is an acceptable value.  I'm doing systems engineering for a new product, and I'm battling an EE who insists a DC output bias is needed, even if not used for either power or signalling.

I believe no DC voltage is needed (other than 0V), but am having trouble showing the spec covers this use-case.

Comment: Dont fight it, add a spec then of DC at 1mA Isc  for cable connect logic status with an indicator  and have a jumper. You must have a fault list for DFT

Comment: You're right, of course.  But we are extraordinarily BOM/COGS-sensitive, so eliminating circuitry as early as possible is a high-priority goal (and a key aspect of my systems engineering).  Still, doing the layout is an acceptable route, as is first-article testing, so long as we can depopulate it when it proves to not be needed.

Comment: DFT , DFM and DFC are all important, so at system level , loose cable detect can use DC

Comment: We are a downstream box with RF power detection on the inputs, so no additional cable presence support is needed (or desired).  Our only use-case (so far) is to control an upstream multiswitch/dCSS that speaks EN50607 over DiSEqC.

Comment: Speculation without proof is not sufficient

Comment: Huh? You edited your comment away from engineering and into philosophy, meaning my initial reply was no longer relevant.  Please don't do that!

Comment: Sorry, but false assumptions and speculations are the causes of Murphy's Law and are major Engineering challenges to spec

Comment: What false assumption?  We've been making systems for decades with great and growing success, and ensuring RF input integrity via RF power sensing has proven itself to be both sufficient and robust.  Or are you talking about something else?  Please be specific.

Comment: Is non 0 DC a false assumption  or not ?  Then leave all AC coupled until confirmed.

Comment: Are you talking about the DiSEqC spec?  Anyhow, I've decided to let the EE have his way with the DC bias, but added requirements that everything he does be enabled/disabled via software, with a default of "disabled", and that the presence or absence of his DC bias must not affect DiSEqC communication.  Which ensures BOM deletions are possible, meaning it's only NRE at this point, not COGS.  A small cost to keep an EE happy.

Comment: And, yes, we need DiSEqC to be AC-coupled to guard against other devices placing DC on the RF input coax (shouldn't happen, but Murphy exists).